# Deploy custom list to SharePoint without console access

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, deployment, caml

I would like to extend a sharepoint site hosted by Network solutions by creating a new list type.  I'd like to develop a custom List using Visual Studio (VS 2008, SP 2007).  I can get the functionality I want to work on my local machine.  My problem is as follows:

Building a project in Visual Studio net results  in a WSP file.  I don't have console access.  Can I upload schema.xml to a hosted solution?  I don't see in Sharepoint Designer where I could upload the schema.

If I can't upload the custom list, what can I do in SharePoint designer to extend lists.  I need additional data held on a calendar/appointment.

Will this work in a hosted environment?  Do I need to get a VPS to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with SharePoint 2007. Your hosting provider may do this for you - you will have to ask them - but its often a real large process as they really don't want to have to support custom stuff.

If you were using SharePoint 2010 then "Sandbox Solutions" are a way of deploying .wsp's with a restricted set of features that limit the resources that can be used and if enabled can be deployed without admin access.

[Developing, Deploying, and Monitoring Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx)

[MSDN - Create a Custom Field, Content Type, List Definition, and List Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx)

Comment: As I expected.  Thanks for confirming.